# Magento amazon integration

Tags: magento

I am trying to develop a module in Magento, which displays the magento products on Amazon.com for selling.
For this I have done a lot of R&D, but I am not getting any results out of this. Also I was looking for a connector or extension as such which can perform integration of Magento with Amazon.I got many extenions but they were all paid extensions.
Please suggest me the approach or suggest me a free connector or extension so that I can accomplish my task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Magento 2 amazon connector(https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/amazon-magento-2-multichannel-integration?utm_source=stackexchange-magento-amazon-magento-2-multichannel-integration-sonker). it will help you to upload your products from magento to amazon marketplace

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Camiloo have Amazon Marketplace integration with a product they call [ChannelUnity](http://www.channelunity.com/). It's a paid-for/subscription based setup, but I've heard they're pretty good. Their previous bought-outright Magento extension I've heard good things about as well.

On another note, this ChannelUnity thing will have the ability to integrate into other marketplaces in the future. Apparently eBay is pegged for the end of July, and they're looking at Pixmania and Play.com integration too at some point in the future.

(I'm not an affiliate of said company, I just find their products good. I spoke to a rep there recently, sounded very helpful).

Comment: Seen a couple of downvotes on this comment lately, completely understandable however. ChannelUnity got really bad shortly after I posted this, and their support people didn't seem to care that their service kept failing for no apparent reason. Future reference: go with M2E Pro -- it's *much* better.

Answer (score 5):

Try [M2E Pro](http://www.m2epro.com/) - it does both eBay and Amazon integration and it's free.

Comment: Hi, but it just supports ebay integration. they have not yet released Magento integration. kindly suggest any other alternative.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought it was already due for release. My mistake.

Comment: from their homepage today:  M2E Pro - eBay / Amazon / Rakuten Magento Integration

Comment: how to make amazon affiliate maegnto store using M2E.

Comment: @vishal, M2e lets you post from Magento to Amazon no the other way around.  It's not able to do what you're looking for.